# Elasticsearch price range filter with currency convert (by selected currency)

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, range, currency, price

The flow of my project :

One user register and enter new entity with the **price: 100 | currency: EUR**

Another user registered and creates a new entity with **price: 252 | currency: USD**

Third user registered and creates a new entity with **price: 321 | currency: INR**

What if I am trying to **filter the records by price range (minimum price and maximum price) and selected currency can be any currency (EUR or USD or INR or any forth currency)**.

```
{
    "_index": "tutors",
    "_type": "tutors",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 2,
    "_ignored": [
        "biography.keyword"
    ],
    "_source": {
        "first_name": "Stewart"
        "last_name": "Brado"
        "currency": "INR"
        "local_rates": [
            {
                "subject_id": 374,
                "hourly_rate": 1200,
                "subject_en_name": "ACT",
                "country_id": 2
            },
            {
                "subject_id": 350,
                "hourly_rate": 700,
                "subject_en_name": "Accounting",
                "country_id": 1
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "tutors",
    "_type": "tutors",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 2,
    "_ignored": [
        "biography.keyword"
    ],
    "_source": {
        "first_name": "Nicole"
        "last_name": "Cross"
        "currency": "USD"
        "local_rates": [
            {
                "subject_id": 371,
                "hourly_rate": 654,
                "subject_en_name": "Art",
                "country_id": 1
            },
            {
                "subject_id": 350,
                "hourly_rate": 890,
                "subject_en_name": "Accounting",
                "country_id": 2
            },
            {
                "subject_id": 150,
                "hourly_rate": 1700,
                "subject_en_name": "Autocad",
                "country_id": 3
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried below query :

```
"function_score" => [
    "functions" => [[
        "script_score" => [
            "script" => [
                "params" => [
                    "USD" => 1,
                    "SGD" => 0.72,
                    "MYR" => 0.24,
                    "INR" => 0.014,
                    "EUR" => 1.12
                ],
                "source" => "doc['local_rates.hourly_rate'].value * params.EUR"
            ]
        ]
    ]]
]
```

Comment: Your query would need to somehow have the exchange rate for each other currencies as it would only make sense to compare amounts in the same currency

Comment: Yes, thats why I have asked this question because right it's only filtering the records but with not converted price.

Comment: Maybe show what you've done so far?

Comment: Now I want to filter these records by Price range - 100 EUR (minimum) to 3000 EUR (maximum)

Comment: @Val
Please let me know if you know about this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please update your question with code details, as it's not readable in comments, thank you

Comment: @Val, I have updated my question with code.